# How to add rowCount in tooltip of google charts

Tags: angularjs, charts, google-visualization

I am using google chart to display my data on screen. Data is aggregated using using one of the column as shown below...

```
 var dataGroup = google.visualization.data.group(
             data, // data table
             [0], // group by column
             [
                 { // aggregation column
                     column: 1,
                     type: 'number',
                     aggregation: google.visualization.data.avg
                 }
             ]
         );
        chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(dataGroup, $scope.getOptionsForChart());
```

Now what I want to do is add row count in tooltip.

THanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are no standard options for **adding** information to the tooltip,
you must replace the entire tooltip with your own custom one...

two things must be in place to use custom html tooltips...

1) must use the following chart option...

```
  tooltip: {
    isHtml: true
  }
```

2) the tooltip column must have the following property...

```
  p: {html: true}
```

---

see following working snippet...

an aggregation column is added for the *count*

then a `DataView` is used to convert the *count* column to a tooltip column

however, when using a `DataView`, for some reason the `html` column property is ignored

so when the chart is drawn, convert the `DataView` back to a `DataTable`,

```
 chart.draw(view.toDataTable(), ...
```

this will allow the chart to recognize the column property...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var datastring = '{"PerformanceData" : [{"ReportName":"ABC","ReportTime":"48"},{"ReportName":"ABC","ReportTime":"48"},{"ReportName":"XYZ","ReportTime":"50"},{"ReportName":"ABC","ReportTime":"48"},{"ReportName":"XYZ","ReportTime":"50"},{"ReportName":"ABC","ReportTime":"48"},{"ReportName":"XYZ","ReportTime":"50"}]}';
    var jsonData = JSON.parse(datastring);
    var chartData = [];

    // load chart data
    jsonData.PerformanceData.forEach(function (row, rowIndex) {
      // column headings
      var columns = Object.keys(row);
      if (rowIndex === 0) {
        chartData.push(columns);
      }

      // row values
      var chartRow = [];
      columns.forEach(function (column, colIndex) {
        var chartCell = row[column];
        if (colIndex > 0) {
          chartCell = parseFloat(chartCell);
        }
        chartRow.push(chartCell);
      });
      chartData.push(chartRow);
    });

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(chartData);

    // group data
    var dataGroup = google.visualization.data.group(
      data,  // data table
      [0],   // group by column
      [
        {    // average
          column: 1,
          type: 'number',
          aggregation: google.visualization.data.avg,
          label: data.getColumnLabel(1)
        },
        {    // count
          column: 1,
          type: 'number',
          aggregation: google.visualization.data.count
        }
      ]
    );

    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(dataGroup);
    view.setColumns([0, 1, {
      type: 'string',
      role: 'tooltip',
      calc: function (dt, row) {
        return '<div class="tooltip">' +
                '<div><span>' + dt.getValue(row, 0) + '</span></div>' +
                '<div><span>' + dt.getColumnLabel(1) + ' (avg): </span>' + dt.getValue(row, 1) + '</div>' +
                '<div><span>Row Count: </span>' + dt.getValue(row, 2) + '</div>' +
               '</div>';
      },
      p: {html: true}
    }]);


    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

    // use group data to draw chart
    chart.draw(view.toDataTable(), {
      tooltip: {
        isHtml: true
      }
    });
  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```

```css
.tooltip {
  font-size: 12pt;
  padding: 8px;
}

.tooltip div {
  padding: 4px;
}

.tooltip span {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```